# Adding a video url to an sms or mms using twilio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube, twilio

I can add a youtube link to a new message's `body` like below and it will send the message, but adding the link to the `media_url` gives an mime type error. Idk how I feel about this method.

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new 'Axx', 'xx'
message = client.messages.create 
    from: '+1xxxxxxxxxx', 
    to: 'xxxxxxxxxx', 
    body: "Learning to send SMS you are. \n https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBlKPLeLU_s"
```

Is there a better way of adding youtube links to a new message?

EDIT

Adding the url to the `media_url` key like

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new 'Axx', 'xx'
message = client.messages.create 
    from: '+1xxxxxxxxxx', 
    to: 'xxxxxxxxxx', 
    body: "Learning to send SMS you are." 
    media_url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBlKPLeLU_s"
```

Gives the error from twilio

> Msg=Attempt+to+retrieve+MediaUrl+returned+an+unsupported+Content-Type.&EmailNotification=false&contentType=text%2Fhtml&LogLevel=ERROR&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2FaBlKPLeLU_s

Comment: May be because the URL provided by Youtube is not having the extension with it, but the URL provided by your application is having the extension with it. so create a method and route where you can pass just a video id and that method return the video in response like youtube.

Comment: How would you do that? I just tried using the embedded version but the contentType is still `text/html`

Comment: Can you show an example of adding the link to a media_url and also post the exact error for reference for everyone that visits this link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you send media via an MMS message with Twilio, you need to link to the media file itself. In your example, you are just linking to the YouTube page, not to the video file.

Some other things to note. [The list of MIME types that Twilio will accept is listed here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/accepted-mime-types). Also, [Twilio will not send media messages that are over 5MB total size](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133547-Will-Twilio-automatically-resize-my-images-for-MMS-messaging-).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Twilio's example of media_url

[Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/messaging/send-messages)

```
  var mediaUrl = new List<Uri>() {
      new Uri("http://www.example.com/hearts.png")
  };
  var to = new PhoneNumber("+14158141829");
  var message = MessageResource.Create(to,
                  from: new PhoneNumber("+15558675309"),
                  body: "Jenny please?! I love you <3",
                  mediaUrl: mediaUrl);
```

> And also the allowed options link

[Twilio Create function arguments](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/reference/twilio-csharp/5.0.0/class_twilio_1_1_rest_1_1_api_1_1_v2010_1_1_account_1_1_create_message_options.html#af040278adde1cfb83acf7f965ac467a9)

> Could you try...

```
client = Twilio::REST::Client.new 'Axx', 'xx'
  message = client.messages.create 
  from: '+1xxxxxxxxxx', 
  to: 'xxxxxxxxxx', 
  body: "Learning to send SMS you are." 
  media_url: [URI("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBlKPLeLU_s")]
```